# erro with const modifier - return types seem ok

Tags: c++

I couldn't resolve this issue....

So I have class Node defined like this (this is a minimal version)

```
class Node {

private:
    std::vector <const Node*> leaves;

public:
    const Node* get_Leaf(int i);
```

I've defined get_Leaf like this

```
const Node* Node::get_Leaf(int i){
    return leaves[i];
}
```

However, I still get the error "cannot convert const Node* to Node*.

Someone please help

Comment: It would be more helpful if you were to post the exact error message you get, along with the line(s) of code about which it is complaining.   :)

Answer (score 3):

Making an assumption here.

```
Node * n;
n->get_Leaf(0);              //works, returns const Node*
n->get_Leaf(0)->get_Leaf(0); //fails, can't call
                             //(const Node* Node::get_Leaf) on const Node*
```

Assumption is that you're calling `get_Leaf` on the returned value of `get_Leaf` or some other function that returns `const Node*`. In that case, you need to declare `get_Leaf` like so: `const Node* get_Leaf(int i) const;`